# Deleting user directories with . in name

Tags: find

I have directories with usernames as "firstname.lastname" and firstname.middle.lastname in one directory.  Is there a way to delete directories with "." in name under current directory.  I need to run this on several servers and trying to find a way to do it with find.  I read the man page for the find but couldn't find any good solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*.*' -exec echo rm -r {} +
```

If that does what you want then remove the `echo`.

Comment: It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Be extremely careful about it, because you might accidentally delete FILES with extensions, e.g. script.sh or log.txt. To remove only directories with . in their names, try:

```
rm -r *.*/
```

after navigating to the directory where you store your user data.